# Does the write-behind queue of a MapLoader get persisted to Hazelcast hot restart stores if they are configured for the region

Tags: hazelcast

If the cluster is shut down, or there is a crash, will the events in the write-behind queue be lost ?

Answer (score 0):

Potentially yes. 
You can configure synchronous or asynchronous which controls the behavior sent back to the client. If you have a synchronous map store and the server goes down then the client is notified of the loss; however, in the event of an asynchronous map store then the client will not be notified and obviously the call to the backend (down stream of hazelcast) will fail.